# What is the range of the target decelerator?

Tags: everspace

The target decelerator simply says "reduces your currently locked target's speed".

What is the effective range of this effect?  If I lock a target that's 5km away, will it reduce their speed at that range?

[image]

Comment: @l I I'm looking into this for you. I will let you know, once I find out!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The target decelerator does not have a range limit.

Source: I contacted Rock Fish Games development team, asked them, and that was their answer.

[image]

Comment: For completeness sake can you please upload a screenshot or a c/p of the conversation?  Thanks!

Comment: Sure, adding it now.

Comment: tyvm! (12 chars)